# Pygame new enemy every 10sec?

Tags: events, pygame, game-development

sorry this question may be a duplicate but i have been searching a lot about this topic and i couldn't do anything. So how can i blit to the screen a new enemy every 10 sec ?
btw i want to implement that using the USEREVENTS as i'm learning them newly.
I'm really having trouble with this kind of events, i can't get them, this is what i tried :

```
a = 10000
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_e:
            pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT+1, a)
if a == 0:
    screen.blit(enemy, (enemyX, enemyY))
    a = 5000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pygame exists a timer event. Use [`pygame.time.set_timer()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer) to repeatedly create a [`USEREVENT`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) in the event queue. The time has to be set in milliseconds. e.g.:

```py
timer_interval = 10000 # 10 seconds
timer_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(timer_event, timer_interval)
```

Note, in pygame customer events can be defined. Each event needs a unique id. The ids for the user events have to be between `pygame.USEREVENT` (24) and `pygame.NUMEVENTS` (32). In this case `pygame.USEREVENT+1` is the event id for the timer event.

Receive the event in the event loop:

```py
run = True
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

         elif event.type == timer_event:
             # [...]
```

The timer event can be stopped by passing 0 to the *time* argument of `pygame.time.set_timer`.

---

Note, you have to use a list to manage the enemies. Add a new enemy position to a list when the event occurs. Iterate through the enemies in a loop. Move and draw the enemies in the loop:

```py
timer_interval = 10000 # 10 seconds
timer_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(timer_event, timer_interval)

enemy_list = []

run = True
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

         elif event.type == timer_event:
             # [...]

             enemy_list.append([enemyX, enemyY])  

    # [...]

    for enemy_pos in enemy_list:
        screen.blit(enemy, enemy_pos)
```

Comment: Thank you, but will the timer be set automatically to 10000 ms again every time the time_interval becomes equal to zero ? or should i do it myself? and btw what's that pygame.NUMEVENTS?

Comment: @Developeeer Yes, as I mentioned in the answer *"Use pygame.time.set_timer() to repeatedly create a USEREVENT in the event queue."* - Reading the documentation would help as well.